# How do I continue my Python script after a error

Tags: python, error-handling, python-3.10

I'm trying to make my own OS using:

```
command = input('['+ location + ']$ ')
if command == 'exit':
    break
elif command == 'open app':
    try:
        app = input('App Name: ')
    except FileNotFoundError():
        print('no such application')
    exec(open('/home/zozijaro/Desktop/ZoziOS/Shell/DownloadedApps/' + app).read())
else:
    print('unknown command: ' + command)
```

When I enter an app name that does not exist, I expect it to print `No Such Application`, and then I should get the chance to try again, but instead I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/zozijaro/Desktop/ZoziOS/Kernel/terminal/terminal.py", line 11, in <module>
exec(open('/home/zozijaro/Desktop/ZoziOS/Shell/DownloadedApps/' + app).read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/zozijaro/Desktop/ZoziOS/Shell/DownloadedApps/app'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using `finally` statement in your error and exception block. check out this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/try-except-else-and-finally-in-python/#:~:text=Finally%20Keyword,terminates%20due%20to%20some%20exception.)

Comment: Also try separating the `open()` call from the `exec` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the exec statement inside try block.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `except FileNotFoundError` follows a `try` block in which you don't try to open any file, thus the `try` block never raises a `FileNotFoundError`, and the `except` block never gets executed.

You should move the `exec(open...` backwards to the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    try:
        app = input('App Name: ')
    except FileNotFoundError():
        print('no such application')
    exec(open('/home/zozijaro/Desktop/ZoziOS/Shell/DownloadedApps/' + app).read())
```

with

```
    try:
        exec(open('/home/zozijaro/Desktop/ZoziOS/Shell/DownloadedApps/' + app).read())
        app = input('App Name: ')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('no such application')
```

Note that I removed the parenthesis around `FileNotFoundError`.